# Change Google Place Picker Appbar Text Color

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I would really like to know if I am able to change the text color of the Appbar text in the PlacePicker API for Android. It should inherit the styling from my application, but it does not do that.

my styles.xml is as follows:

```
<style name="MaterialParent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="icon">@color/icons</item>
    <item name="divider">@color/divider</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent_alpha26</item>

</style>

<style name="Material" parent="MaterialParent"/>
```

I've already tried changing `android:textColorPrimary`, `android:textColorSecondary` and `textColor` to white with no luck.

[image]

Comment: i have same issue too..

Comment: have you got solution???

Comment: The only way out I found is, using a darker colorPrimary. Google, give us customization. I would like to change the title text too.

Comment: @SanketKachhela i am also facing the same issue, how do you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instade of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the colorPrimary value of color file with the color hex code, that you want and it works fine.